# Cannot convert method group 'getRondes' to non-delegate type 'Label'

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to put some text from the dll in the label. But it gives me an error:
"Cannot convert method group 'getRondes' to non-delegate type 'Label' ".

this is my code from the dll file:

```
public class Controller
{

    private Spel _spel;
    public void setSpelerMonster(string naam)
    {
        _spel.setSpelerMonster(naam);
    }
    public void setComputernaam(string naam)
    {
        _spel.setcomputernaam(naam);
    }
    public void setSpelerMonsterattack(int attack)
    {
         _spel.setSpelerMonsterattack(attack);
    }
    public void setcomputerattack(int attack)
    {
        _spel.setattack(attack);
    }
    public string getSpelerMonster()
    {
        return _spel.Speler.ToString();
    }
    public string getComputerMonster()
    {
        return _spel.Computer.ToString();
    }
    public int getRondes()
    {
        return _spel.Rondes;
    }
    public bool speelRonde()
    {
        return _spel.speelRonde();
    }
    public Controller()
    {
        _spel = new Spel();
    }
}
```

and this is the code for my wpf project:

```
 private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtnaam.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnstart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        lblprogram.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        sldaanvalskracht.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnvalaan.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        lblprogram = C.getRondes();
    }
```

C.getRondes(); gives  the error but i don't why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the label you need to change its `Content`, you should have something like this:

```
lblprogram.Content = C.getRondes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a Label (which I assume is what lblprogram is) to an integer (which is what getRondes returns.

You probably want

```
lblprogram.Text = getRondes().toString();
```

Comment: it stil give me an error because there is not .Text method with lblprogram.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using Windows Forms. Content is the property you want.